# What is the purpose of "i = (i < arr.length) ? i : 0"?

Tags: javascript, image

I cannot understand how this changes images in JavaScript?
mainly I am having troubles with this line

```
i = (i < images.length) ? i : 0;
```

how does this reset and decide the image:

```
var images = [];
images[0] = "image1";
images[1] = "image2";
images[2] = "image3";
images[3] = "image4";
images[4] = "image5";
images[5] = "image6";

var i = 0;
setInterval(fadeDivs, 3000);

function fadeDivs() {
    i = (i < images.length) ? i : 0;
    console.log(i)
    $('.product img').fadeOut(100, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', images[i]).fadeIn(100);
    })
    i++;
}
```

Comment: [Ternary Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: thanks forgot that one pretty cool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called the ternary operator. Breaking down this line:

```
i = i < images.length ? i : 0;
```

...here's what's going on. The statement is basically saying:

```
 i = (if this is true) ? (assign this value) : (otherwise assign this);
```

...so if "i" is less than "images.length", it will keep its value (i = i), otherwise, it will reset (i = 0).

Answer (score 3):

`i = i < images.length ? i : 0;` ensures that value of `i` remains a valid array index - it resets the value of `i` to 0 if its value crosses `images.length` - thus, allowing one to cycle through the `images` array.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense. I will explain.

```
var i = 0; //the position of the image in the array "images"

//set the interval. 
//After three seconds call "fadeDivs"
setInterval(fadeDivs, 3000); 

function fadeDivs() {

    //If the value of i is not longer than the length
    //of the images array, then use the current value of i
    //If the value is greater than the length of images
    //reset the value of i to 0
    i = i < images.length ? i : 0; 

    //find the top image and fade it out
    $('.product img').fadeOut(100, function(){

        //now that it is faded out, change the src
        //attribute to the next image url in the array
        $(this).attr('src', images[i]).fadeIn(100);

    })

    //increment i for the next image image url
    i++;
}
```

It looks like the question was edited for clarity after I posted my original answer. Yes, it is as others said- a ternary operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Which is basically an if/then statement that returns a value. The two lines of code below are functionally the same, but a ternary operator is more elegant.

```
i = function(){if(i<images.length){return i}else{return 0}}()

i = i < images.length ? i : 0
```

Hope this helps.